What's the difference between a voucher and a gift card?
Does a voucher feature a particular product or a particular service you can get for that voucher while a gift card features a monetary value for which you can get any service or product at a given place?

Also report what you find in a dictionary.

A voucher is usually given by a business, perhaps by way of a refund, or complimentary. A gift card is a present from friend/family. Sometimes a voucher is a promotion for a specific product: "50% off your next X", but a gift card isn't usually restricted.

Thank you but are my assumptions above incorrect?

The real difference is that "voucher" has many meanings (many types of tokens, tickets, passes, substitutes for money, etc) but "gift card" has a more specific meaning. Although "gift voucher" is for most practical purposes interchangeable with "gift card".

Can you perhaps show me pictures?

Where are you from, idk29, that these differences puzzle you?

I don't think it's relevant where I am from. But can you please show me pictures and explain what the differences are?

On this site, when a question is closed as a duplicate, the questioner is expected to go to the page that it is a duplicate of, and read it. If that does not resolve the matter, one should explain why it doesn't, before pursuing the matter further.
